# How to enter cash back from credit card payment in account?

Tags: credit

If you purchase petrol and pay by credit card, when some charge are reversed,  then your card  is credited. How does one enter this statement for accounting purposes?

Comment: Enter it where?  Are you using a particular software tool for your personal accounting, or are you using some sort of paper system?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an accounting package, just enter a 'money received' type of transaction to your credit card account, booked to the same expense account used for the original transaction. This reverses the original transaction by the amount received. If the 'spend money' and 'receive money' transactions are booked on different days, reports that don't cover both dates won't see both of them. This reflects the reality of what happened.

The accounting would be as follows, based on the CR/DR explained at, say, [leoissac.com](http://www.leoisaac.com/fin/fin004.htm):

- Petrol Expense decrease: $x CR
- Credit Card Liability decrease (or Bank Account Asset increase): $x DR